# How to iterate list inside a lambda filter stream in Java 8?

Tags: java, loops, lambda

I have a Car class, each Car class has a list of Wheel class and each Wheel class has a integer field airPressure.

```
public class Car {
  private List<Wheel> wheels;
  public List<Wheel> getWheels() {
    return wheels;
  }
}

public class Wheel {
  private int airPressure;
  public int getAirPressure() {
    return airPressure;
  }
}
```

Now I have a list of Cars and I have to filter out all cars that have any wheels' air pressure larger than defaultValue. I'm filtering cars but I need to iterate through all wheels. Now I have code like this:

```
I have: List<Cars> cars, int defaultValue
List<Cars> filteredCars = cars.stream()
  .filter(car -> car.getWheels().get(0).getAirPressure() < defaultValue)
  .filter(car -> car.getWheels().get(1).getAirPressure() < defaultValue)
  .filter(car -> car.getWheels().get(2).getAirPressure() < defaultValue)
  ...
```

How to iterate wheels of each car when filtering cars?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/) howto page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will select only cars with all wheels' air pressure below `defaultValue`:

```
List<Car> filteredCars = cars.stream()
        .filter(car -> car.getWheels()
                .stream()
                .allMatch(wheel -> wheel.getAirPressure() < defaultValue))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what's the simplest way to find the max value of airPressure of all wheels of all cars?

Comment: `cars.stream().map(Car::getWheels).flatMap(List::stream).mapToInt(Wheel::getAirPressure).max()`